# Django Forms ErrorList custom format HTML tags

Tags: django, django-forms

In Django version 3.2 you can customize the error list format. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format

However in version 4.1 it has changed?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#customizing-the-error-list-format

This section is very vague for me:[image]

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField, CaptchaTextInput

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "first name"}), required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "last name"}), required=False)
    from_email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "email"}), required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "subject"}), required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "message"}), required=True)
    captcha = CaptchaField(widget=CaptchaTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "placeholder": "prove u r not a bot "}), required=True)
```

In my template, I need `{{ form.captcha.errors }}`  to  be displayed with another HTML tag and not the default `<ul class="errorlist">`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

### ======= html code =======

```
{% block body %}
     <form action="" method="POST" novalidate >
          {% csrf_token %}
          
          <p>{{form.name.label}}:{{form.name}} </p>
               
          <p><button type="submit">Add</button></p>
          
     </form>

     <p style="background-color: #ffcccc;">{{form.name.errors|striptags}}</span></p>

{% endblock body %}
```

### ==== output =====

[image]